# D3.js: Exteding the y-axis without making any changes to the existing chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning D3.js and using this code: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579
I changed the data sets a bit and they all occupy the whole chart(the values are quite closer and larger than the given example). I now want to extend the y axis(and reduce the bar size).

**Things that I tried:**
In the rect attr, I changed the attribute `height` to `height/2`, but this only changes the height of the rectangle size but the not the values of the y axis.

Tried to change the range values of y axis from `[height,0]` to `[height/2, 0]`, still no luck.

How do I achieve this? Also, I am using "s" as the tickFormat(not percentages as in the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `y.domain` to fit your data. So, edit this line

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

For example, this will make the chart axis go from 0 to 100%:

```
y.domain([0, 1]); // 0% to 100%
```